# Servlet Throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when class in path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am writing a simple servlet and trying to create an instance of one of my classes, `DataStore`, in the code.

This class is public and sits in a file called `DataStore.java` in the same package as the Servlet code.

When I try to create a new instance in the code:

```
DataStore dStore = new DataStore();
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backend.DataStore
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at backend.AjaxServlet.createGame(AjaxServlet.java:196)
```

I tried creating an instance of this class in a differnet file and it worked great.
Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Is your scenario that you are deploying a war file that uses multiple jars?

Comment: what do you mean by "I tried creating an instance of this class in a differnet file and it worked great." ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If JVM throws ClassNotFoundException the class is not found in classpath. It means that something is not configured correctly.

So, check the class (i mean file `backend.DataStore.class`). It's path should be: your `web application folder/WEB-INF/classes/backend/DataStore.class`. If this class is packaged into separate jar file this jar must be under `YOUR_WEB_APP/WEB-INF/lib/yourjar.jar`

Comment: Agreed, and the class folder must correspond to the package definition inside the .java file.

Comment: Thank You. For some reason the file was created as dataStore.class and not DataStore.class, deleted the directory, clean & build fix it.

Comment: it probably happened because you changed the class name using re-factoring option in eclipse. Anyway I am glad you found the problem. Good luck.